# Set value of enum in xml from resource

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am building a custom attribute for a custom view which is an `enum` type.
I know that every optional value must be with a name and value. I want that the value will be given from another resource as shown in the following example (in file attrs.xml):

Integer resource:

```
<integer name="example">0</integer>
```

Stylable declaration:

```
<declare-styleable name="FontStyleTextView" format="enum">
    <attr name="typeFace">
        <enum name="name1" value="@integer/example"/>
        <enum name="name2" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

The error that I get is:

```
error: Tag <enum> or <flag> 'value' attribute must be a number, not "@integer/example"
```

Is there any possible way to give the value field a value from another resource?

Answer (score 0):

No. Like the error says "attribute must be a number" and you are trying to use a reference.